# Unknown bootstrap component

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been given an assignment to recreate a form from a given image. I'm using bootstrap 3, but can't recreate the following images. At the moment I'm using a label with a rounded radius but it doesn't look the same. Can someone point out the right component I should be using?

[image: image of what i am looking for]
[image: image of what i am looking for]

Comment: Why not use the plus sign glyphicon? http://www.bootply.com/bBBwnWXKHb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [fontawesomes](http://fontawesome.io/) [stacked icons](http://fontawesome.io/examples/#stacked) concept. But this would make the icon bigger that yours. Otherwise, as you pointed out by your self, you could use a `badge` or `label` and restyle it the way you need it, by modifying the `border-radius` or anything else, which doesn't fit your needs...

```
<!-- just some example code -->
Deposit 
<span class="fa-stack">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-plus fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
</span>

Priority Payment? <span class="label label-default" style="border-radius:100%">?</span>
Deporit <span class="badge">+</span>
```

PS: Note that you would have to override all border-radius-prefixes which is better done in a css class (as always). The inline css here is of course just for the sake of simplicity

Comment: I decided to go with changing the border radius, instead of the font awesome icons. Thank you for pointing it out through